# How can I have a picture expand across the entire background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have pictures that I would like to have expand across an entire page but I don't know how to duplicate this effect with different resolutions. How could this be done? See here my current example: http://frdsc.net/GK8MHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to write an answer, but I know of an article which answers your question perfectly.

**[Perfect Full Page Background Image @ CSS-Tricks.com by Chris Coyer](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)**

Comment: Yes, because content duplication sucks!!! (No seriously, I expect better answers from you than this.)

Comment: I fail to see the need to write a full fledged answer when the EXACT PROBLEM, the EXACT **SPECIFIC** PROBLEM is already solved. In that case, there's no need to duplicate content, no.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Supersized is a great jQuery plug-in!

Answer (score 0):

Some people I did work with at One Mighty Roar build this very popular plugin to accomplish exactly what you are asking about (if you still need it), i'd go with this.

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/